# How do sort Object based on other object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am having two objects say `firstObject` and `secondObject` . Now i have to sort `firstObject` in such a way thats its value matched by `secondObject` .Here are objects

`firstObject`

```
     0:{id: 23, code: "SONGS", value: "Songs"}
     1:{id: 24, code: "ATHELETE", value: "Athelete"}
     2:{id: 25, code: "DANCE", value: "Dance"}
     3:{id: 28, code: "MUSIC_BASE", value: "Music base"}
     4:{id: 31, code: "SPORTS", value: "Sports"}
```

`secondObjects`

```
   {"Sports":2,"Dance":3,"Music base":4,"Athelete":3,"Songs":1}
```

After sorting `firstObject` should have order `Sports ,Dance ,Music base ,Athelete ,Songs`

Comment: You just need to create a new array

Comment: Your secondObject order for each key, `Sports ,Dance ,Music base ,Athelete ,Songs`, is **not** guaranteed to have the same order as you expect. Object keys are not guaranteed to be kept ordered by any javascript engine (and I've personally ran into problems before where I assumed they would be ordered and they aren't). So what you're asking for is possible only depending on what javascript engine you're using. Otherwise you need to figure out another way to decide the order.

Comment: @Alexander some how i have to sort same object , because same is used in different mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a function which will compare `Object.keys(secondObj).indexOf(a.value) - Object.keys(secondObj).indexOf(b.value)`. As you need to compare value index of keys in the secondObj based on the value of current element.

```js
var firstObj = [{id: 23, code: "SONGS", value: "Songs"},
{id: 24, code: "ATHELETE", value: "Athelete"},
{id: 25, code: "DANCE", value: "Dance"},
{id: 28, code: "MUSIC_BASE", value: "Music base"},
{id: 31, code: "SPORTS", value: "Sports"}]

var secondObj = {"Sports":2,"Dance":3,"Music base":4,"Athelete":3,"Songs":1};

var sorted = firstObj.sort(
  (a,b) => Object.keys(secondObj).indexOf(a.value) - Object.keys(secondObj).indexOf(b.value)
);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: thanx for your time but it is not sorted in desired order.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment to your original question, object keys are not guaranteed to be ordered, so your question is inherently flawed.

BUT if we wanted to assume you would always be running in engines where object keys are kept ordered, you could do something like this:

```
let firstObj = [{id: 23, code: "SONGS", value: "Songs"},
    {id: 24, code: "ATHELETE", value: "Athelete"},
    {id: 25, code: "DANCE", value: "Dance"},
    {id: 28, code: "MUSIC_BASE", value: "Music base"},
    {id: 31, code: "SPORTS", value: "Sports"}];

let secondObj = {"Sports":2,"Dance":3,"Music base":4,"Athelete":3,"Songs":1};

let newArray = [];
Object.keys(secondObj).forEach(key => {
    newArray.push(firstObj.find(o => o.value === key));
});
```

`newArray` would have firstObj in the same order as the keys from secondObj